# How to paste character string based on 'this' condition in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I have this data frame `df`

```
df

 col1                          col2 
Engraulis encrasicolus        Engraulis encrasicolus 
Sardina pilchardus            Sardina pilchardus
Scomber spp                   Scomber
Spicara                       Spicara


class(df)
"factor"
```

I would like paste letters 'spp' in `col2` every time that is present in `col1` 
for example:

```
       col1                          col2 
Engraulis encrasicolus        Engraulis encrasicolus 
Sardina pilchardus            Sardina pilchardus
Scomber spp                   Scomber spp
Spicara                       Spicara
```

I tried with:

```
df.res <- ifelse(df$col1 %like% "spp"==T,
       paste("spp",collapse=NULL) %in% df$col2,df$col1)
```

but the result is a similar data frame `df` with character string and value logic FALSE:

```
df.res                  
"Engraulis encrasicolus"        
"Sardina pilchardus"         
"FALSE"                
"Spicara"
```

Comment: You need something like `paste(df$col2, "spp")`.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the transformation you want to do, or even what the transformation is.

Comment: The logic is that col2 contain exactly name species from a comparison with an on-line database (col1 not, for example can contain writing mistakes), but 'spp' is missed and I need to paste it based on col1

Comment: `df$col2[grepl("spp$", df$col1)] <- paste(df$col2[grepl("spp$", df$col1)], "spp")` should do

Comment: A. Suliman....only when is present in the col1, your code paste always spp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Base R:

```
df.res <- ifelse(grepl("spp", df$col1),
                 paste0(df$col2, " spp"), df$col2)
```

Or as an additional column in the original data frame:

```
df$col3 <- ifelse(grepl("spp", df$col1),
                  paste0(df$col2, " spp"), df$col2)
```